# DSA questions on multidimensional array of coordinate system where keeping y same and maximum distance constant, find no of changes

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, cartesian-coordinates

Task details

Problem Statement:

N distinct flags are placed on x- y plane. You need to rearrange the flags such that following conditions are satisfied

> All have same y coordinated

> Maximum distance between any two points should be N-1

> They should all be at different positions

For this rearrangement you can move a flag from (x, y) to (x+1, y) or (x-1, y) or (x, y+1) or (x, y-1). This operation can be performed any number of times for all the flag. Performing this operation costs 1 unit per operation.

Find the minimum number of times you need to apply the operation to satisfy the above conditions.

Note - At any point of time you cannot allow two flags to be at same position.

Input:

First line of input contains N

N lines follow each of which contains the coordinate of ith flag xi yi

Constraints:

1 <= N <= 100000

-1000000000 <= xi, yi <= 1000000000

Output:

Return a single integer which is the minimum number of operations required to perform the rearrangement

Example

Sample input 1:

2

1 0

2 1

Sample output 1:

1

Explaination1 - We can move flag 1 from (1, 0) to (1, 1)

Sample input 2:

3

1 1

2 2

3 3

Sample output 2:

2

Explaination1 - We can move flag 1 from (1, 1) to (1, 2) and flag 2 from (3, 3) to (3, 2)

I tried using ChatGPT and Gemini advance but none of the answers pass more than 2-3 test case. If anybody can tell me about its solution with slight explanation or even the right approach. It would be great help if I can get a js solution.

Comment: Do not tag this as `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide the code you used, which failed? Perhaps it would be easier to suggest corrections, than to make the entire thing from scratch.